# Looking at similar sequences between merged data frames

Tags: r

I am new to R, and would like some help regarding the following issue. I currently have 2 patients which 2 treatments for each patient. I would like to see what unique gene sequences are only in one of the treatment groups, and subsequently compare the same treatment to see if the same gene occurs in both patients. I was able to separate out the genes that were present in one treatment group for each patient, however, I am having trouble with the second part in which I would like to see if the same sequences are in both patients. Here is my code:

```
a=!is.na(merged11$AS1_ITD_cloneCount)
b=is.na(merged11$AS1_WT_cloneCount)
merged2<-merge(merged1,AS3_WT,by.x="clonalSequence",by.y="clonalSequence",all=T)
Patient_1_Difference <- merged2[a&b, c("clonalSequence","AS1_ITD_cloneCount","AS1_WT_cloneCount","aaSeqCDR3.x","aaSeqCDR3.y")]
P3a=!is.na(Patient_3_merge$AS3_ITD_cloneCount)
P3b=is.na(Patient_3_merge$AS3_WT_cloneCount)
Patient_3_merge <- merge(AS3_WT,AS3_ITD,by.x="clonalSequence",by.y="clonalSequence",all=T)
Patient_1_and_3_ITD_merge <- merge(merged2, Patient_3_merge, by.x="clonalSequence",by.y="clonalSequence",all=T)
Patient_1_and_3_ITD <- Patient_1_and_3_ITD_merge[a&b&P3a&P3b, c("clonalSequence","AS1_ITD_cloneCount","AS3_ITD_cloneCount","aaSeqCDR3.x.x","aaSeqCDR3.y.y")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the frequency of each sequence. The function `table()` calculates the frequency. I put the data in a dataframe using data.table to make it easier to see. I hope this answers your question.

```
library(data.table)
x <- as.data.table(table(yourdata))
```